# Kernel of the map $S_n\rightarrow GL_n(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: matrices, group-theory, permutations

$S_n$ is the symmetric group on $n$ letters and $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ is the group of $n$ by $n$ invertible matrices with real entries.

I was watching an algebra lecture series which mentioned twice that the map below has no kernel. Here the map is constructed by placing a $1$ in the $i$-th row of the $j$-th column representing where each $j$-th element of $S_n$ is sent.

Thus $S_n$ is mapped to a matrix that has a unique $1$ in a given row and column and all the other entries are $0$.

> > $S_n\rightarrow GL_n(\mathbb{R})$

Am I mistaken to think that the kernel is the identity permutation (i.e., leaving all the elements of $S_n$ in their original position) which maps to the identity martix $I\in GL_n(\mathbb{R})$?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by it has no kernel.. identity is always there.. you are right the map is injective

Comment: no kernel meaning trivial kernel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct, often people say there is 'no kernel' when they mean that the kernel is trivial (that is containing only the identity element).

There is no ambiguity here as the identity element is always in the kernel, but the language is misleading.